# How to update key's value in json file by Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, request

I want collect data from different pages, but when i get data and append to json file it is structurally bad. i have one dict `num` and i want to append all data in value as list. for example

`num:[1,2,3]`

**after adding**

`num:[1,2,3,4,5]`

this is my code -->

```
import requests
import json
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import os


num_list=[]
def req(i):
    url = 'Website_link{}'.format(i)
    x = requests.get(url, headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "ka",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Host": "api2.myauto.ge",
        "Origin": "https://www.myauto.ge",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Referer": "https://www.myauto.ge/",
        "sec-ch-ua": "'Not A;Brand';v='99', 'Chromium';v='96', 'Google Chrome';v='96'",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site"})

    dict_to_json = json.loads(x.content.decode("utf-8"))
    pretty_json = json.dumps(dict_to_json, indent=4)
    return dict_to_json


def list_append(parse):
    for i in parse["data"]["items"]:
        num_list.append(str(i["client_phone"]))


def write_to_json():
    num_dict={"num":num_list}
    if os.stat("data.json").st_size == 0:
        f = open("data.json", "w")
        json.dump(num_dict, f, indent=2)
        f.close()
    else:
        f = open("data.json","r+")
        data=json.load(f)
        f.close()

        f = open("data.json", "a")

        data["num"]+=([num_list])
        json.dump(data,f,indent=2)
        f.close()



for i in range(1,3):
    sleep(randint(3, 5))

    req_load=req(i)
    list_append(req_load)
    write_to_json()
    num_list=[]
```

**I get such data**

````
  "num": [
    "995579448820",
    "995595334438",
    "995555154416",
    "995577025245",
    "995599485252",
    "995597083412",
    "995598919090",
    "995599401516",
    "995597092860",
    "995551317007",
    "995577063439",
    "995514213366",
    "995592088897",
    "995577539231",
    "995596940606"
  ]
}{
  "num": [
    "995579448820",
    "995595334438",
    "995555154416",
    "995577025245",
    "995599485252",
    "995597083412",
    "995598919090",
    "995599401516",
    "995597092860",
    "995551317007",
    "995577063439",
    "995514213366",
    "995592088897",
    "995577539231",
    "995596940606",
    [
      "995597032700",
      "995595201008",
      "995593620467",
      "995555605884",
      "995555183888",
      "995597777422",
      "995577125074",
      "995595910006",
      "995595910006",
      "995577583288",
      "995599037070",
      "995558830303",
      "995591085255",
      "995597777608",
      "995555788888"
    ]
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
data["num"]+=([num_list])
```

You are assuming that `num_list` is not an array and you are currently wrapping it inside another one. So you are adding not a list of values but another array to your currently stored inside the json data.

To solve this just change your code to:

```
data["num"]+=num_list
```

Besides that, you are writing in append mode and you are updating the json data on memory before writing to disk. Change the mode to write like this:

```
# change
f = open("data.json", "a")
# to
f = open("data.json", "w")
```

About the output you shared there is a weird format at the start. Is that right?

Comment: I think you are right, how do you think about fixing?

Comment: Just remove the brackets. You dont need them there.

Comment: I did but same result

Comment: no sorry, it is not same but wrong again. can u see? https://pastebin.com/6YueAyP5

Comment: Oh! Now I understand the meaning of the begining part of the output you initially shared... That happens because you are using append as the file mode, hence when you write it appends the new array to the end of the file.

Comment: thank you very much!